# How to improve paths in Node

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, autocomplete, path, webstorm

I have lots of directory paths in a Node module and I'd like to have code completion in IntelliJ\WebStorm (or any other IDE).

Below is an example of how I'm currently doing it. It doesn't give me code completion but at least I don't have to type the entire path:

```
export const sharedFolder = assetServerFolder + 'Shared/';
export const sharedTsFolder = sharedFolder + 'Scripts/App/Ts/';
export const sharedImagesFolder = sharedFolder + 'Content/Images/';
```

Does anyone have a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

When you are joining paths you should use the `path.join` function to make your code more portable. See:

- https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths

Good info:

- [Tips for Writing Portable Node.js Code](https://gist.github.com/domenic/2790533)
- [Writing cross-platform Node.js](https://shapeshed.com/writing-cross-platform-node/)

Comment: Thanks. I'd considered converting them to path objects. However the context is Grunt config objects on Windows and Linux for which `/` works fine. 

None of this will give me code completion in the IDE.